# Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense does not show error when a class has not been imported

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I'm doing my first tests in **sonarqube** with one of my repositories (in Laravel) and it caught an error about an undefined *Exception* class:

`Create class "Exception" in namespace or check correct import of class`

Which is correct.

I use Intelephense in Visual Studio Code and it usually warns about these type of error. But in this case, it's not detected, even though if I ask for the class definition, it can't get it, showing this message:

`No definition found for 'Exception'`

Am I missing something? It's a problem on my VSCode configuration?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are importing the Exception class.

Comment: The question is just I'm not importing the Exception class and Sonarqube marks it as an error but Intelephense on Visual Code does not.